# I'm not sure why this is throwing and exception

Tags: c

`

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int charCounter = 0;
    int intCounter = 0;
    int otherCounter = 0;
    int ch;
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("infile.txt", "r");
    while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (isalpha(ch)) {
            charCounter += 1;
        }
        else if (isdigit(ch))
        {
            intCounter += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            otherCounter += 1;
        }
    }

    printf("There were %d char values \n there were %d int values \n there were %d other values ", charCounter, intCounter, otherCounter);
    close(fp);
}
```

`

My code throws an exception after the `while` statement, and I'm not sure why

I'm new to C so im not sure where to start on this

Comment: If `infile.txt` doesn't exist in the current directory, `fopen()` will return NULL, and then you try to use it (e.g. in `getc(fp)`) you'll dereference a NULL pointer and invoke undefined behavior.  Therefore you should check the value returned by `fopen()` to make sure it's not NULL, before trying to use it.  Also, when `fp` is non-NULL and you're done using it, you should close it with `fclose()`, not `close()`.

Comment: is there a way to ensure it won't return null? @JeremyFriesner

Comment: you can’t ensure that it won’t return NULL on error, you can only test for it and return if it is NULL… but the file could always be missing or inaccessible for some reason

Comment: alright, is there a way to make sure the file is found?

Comment: you didn’t get me: you can’t ENSURE it. There may always be a possible scenario where the file does not exist and cannot be created due to disk errors, missing permissions, insufficient space, whatever. you will have to test for it

Comment: C doesn't throw exceptions.

Comment: The way to ensure it doesn't return NULL is to make sure the file exists and is readable... but if that's all you do, you'll have a program that works as long as the file is there, but crashes as soon as you (or anyone) deletes or renames the file and then runs your program again.  Since you probably don't want that, your program should test for failure:   `FILE * fp = fopen(...); if (fp != NULL) {/* code to use fp goes here */ fclose(fp);} else printf("hey the file couldn't be opened!\n");`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what "throwing an exception" means in C.  Here are the changes I made:

1. Added missing include files.
2. Add error check for `fopen()`.
3. Used `fclose()` instead of the incorrect `close()`.  Your compiler should have complained.
4. Added a newline to `printf()`.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* fp = fopen("infile.txt", "r");
    if(!fp) {
        printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    int charCounter = 0;
    int intCounter = 0;
    int otherCounter = 0;
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (isalpha(ch)) {
            charCounter += 1;
        } else if (isdigit(ch)) {
            intCounter += 1;
        } else {
            otherCounter += 1;
        }
    }
    printf("There were %d char values \n there were %d int values \n there were %d other values\n",
        charCounter, intCounter, otherCounter);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

and here is the output with a copy of the above program as "infile.txt":

```
There were 375 char values 
 there were 7 int values 
 there were 232 other values
```